# DNS server for blacklisting tons of domains and also some TLDs

Tags: debian, dns, adblock, rpz

I'm trying to setup a basic DNS server for my lan that is able to put in a nullroute or 127.0.0.1 lots of domains.

The domains I want to block come from a list but I also want to block some domains using regular expressions (this is a must for my setup).

My candidate software for doing this business seemed to be Unbound, a recursive caching secure DNS server with various useful functions.

**However Unbound doesn't seem to support any regular expression!**

Also, Unbound is very picky when it comes for zones repetitions. My domain list is builded from many mixed sources so I can have many repetitions that I filter out with some scripts but also domains in list like:

**aaah.very.this.com**

but also

**very.this.com**

This lead Unbound scream for errors because there is a zone repetition.

While this is a minor issue, that I can remove by cleaning even better the domain list, my main issue is the lack of regexp for handling the domain requests.

Can i somehow block all *.com or *.biz or stuff like that?

```
[\w\.\-]+.com A 127.0.0.1
[\w\.\-]+.com AAAA ::1
```

My regex is an example, i could go with more complex ones...

### BONUS

Can I instead do something even more nasty? Have everything pointing to nullroute or 127.0.0.1 and ONLY a whitelist of domains get resolved by being forwarded to an external DNS ?

If replying please do not forget this extra question as I am very interesting in knowing the answer.

**What i can go for? Bind9, dnsmasq, unbound, pdns-recursor...**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intercepting domains/requests at the DNS service level or redirecting IP netblocks routes to 127.0.0.1/null route are two very different things.

From my point of view, the DNS level is more efficient and more light on resources.

At IP level/null route blocks more effectively, however it is more cumbersome to manage, and slightly more heavy on CPU usage when used in a wider scale.

Please do bear in mind that using blacklists at DNS level can often reach names in the range of the hundred of thousands, and it is not viable to have such large routing tables.

I myself have investigated doing blacklisting via dnsmasq or BIND. I use DNS blacklisting for adverts, malware and to block my smart TV calling home (LG sites).

I ended up using Response Policy Zone in BIND because it does allow some simple regexps, namely * at the end of names, which greatly reduces the blacklist size. [DNS Response Policy Zones](https://dnsrpz.info)

Please do bear in mind RPZ in BIND is supported from 9.8+ BIND, which should be the case in any modern Linux distribution.

As I have the RPZ functionality configured, the domains/DNS names that match the string/regexp simply are answered as non-existent by the BIND DNS server. All the other names that do not match are resolved by the usual process.

As a short example of a few lines of my `/etc/bind/rpz.db`:

```
*.ad.lgappstv.com CNAME .
*.yumenetworks.com CNAME .
*.smartclip.net CNAME .
*.smartshare.lgtvsdp.com CNAME .
*.ibis.lgappstv.com CNAME .
*.doubleclick.net CNAME .
*.l.doubleclick.net CNAME .
*.302br.net CNAME .
*.liveadvert.com CNAME .
*.easysuperdownload-1.com CNAME .
*.easysuperdownload-2.com CNAME .
*.itrackpop.com CNAME .
```

Using your example:

```
*.this.com CNAME .
*.biz CNAME .
```

Please do note that it might not be the best of the ideas to block entire TLDs.

BIND is not as picky as Unbound about repetitions. It will allow aaaa.this.com and this.com; however it won't allow this.com to be defined more than one time.

As for the setup of RPZ itself, I will refer you to my answer on this question on Unix & Linux [Large zone file for bind9 : ad-blocking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253841/large-zone-file-for-bind9-ad-blocking/253879)

For a ready made similar project using a raspberry PI, please see: [Pi-Hole: A Black Hole for Internet Advertsiments](http://pi-hole.net) That project will also direct you to some known free blacklists.

From https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/blob/master/adlists.default

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StevenBlack/hosts/master/hosts

# Other lists we consider safe:
http://adblock.gjtech.net/?format=unix-hosts
http://mirror1.malwaredomains.com/files/justdomains
http://sysctl.org/cameleon/hosts
https://zeustracker.abuse.ch/blocklist.php?download=domainblocklist
https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_tracking.txt
https://s3.amazonaws.com/lists.disconnect.me/simple_ad.txt

# hosts-file.net list. Updated frequently, but has been known to block legitimate sites.
http://hosts-file.net/ad_servers.txt

# Mahakala list. Has been known to block legitimage domains including the entire .com range.
# Warning: Due to the sheer size of this list, the web admin console will be unresponsive.
#http://adblock.mahakala.is/

# ADZHOSTS list. Has been known to block legitimate domains
#http://optimate.dl.sourceforge.net/project/adzhosts/HOSTS.txt

# Windows 10 telemetry list - warning this one may block windows update
#https://raw.githubusercontent.com/crazy-max/HostsWindowsBlocker/master/hosts.txt

# Securemecca.com list - Also blocks "adult" sites (pornography/gambling etc)
#http://securemecca.com/Downloads/hosts.txt

# Quidsup's tracker list
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quidsup/notrack/master/trackers.txt
```

As for whitelisting, apparently it can be done.

If done in a domain by domain basis, it is a matter of setting up a proxy BIND DNS server, that does not have the hints of the root name servers.

However, each allowed domain has to be created with forwarders to a DNS that talks to the outside. This theoretical article sums pretty nicely the idea. [Use DNS whitelists to stop malware in its tracks](http://www.netcraftsmen.com/use-dns-whitelists-to-stop-malware-in-its-tracks/)

Using RPZ in BIND again to our rescue, the configuration can be much simpler, and without needing to setup up a proxy DNS server.

As a variation in the configuration of this page, [RPZ revisited](http://jpmens.net/2011/10/24/rpz-revisited/), you will have a normally configured BIND, with RPZ white lists, and then you will black everything in the normal rpz policy (e.g. * or *.* ).

```
options {
 ....
response-policy { 
   zone "rpz-white" policy PASSTHRU; // my own white list
   zone "rpz-foreign";    // obtained from producer
};
}
```

Whist the white-listing deny-it-all approach is certainly insane, whitelisting can have it uses to exempt a particular domain that is being hit by a black listing wider match.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, tomorrow I will try to set it up. However there's still my final part unanswered: It is possible apply an insane reverse way ? Blacklist all by default and allow only what i want from a certain list? Plus some additional block rules at the bottom? Eg: all blacklisted, accept only .co.uk and blacklist again bad.co.uk , bad2.co.uk and bad3.co.uk

Comment: It can be done. Added to the answer. Are you setting up labs?

Comment: Trying atm, but I figured out my debian bind is too old `BIND 9.9.5-9+deb8u6-Debian (Extended Support Version)`, indeed I get a message: `unknown option 'response-policy'` by checking the bind config ;) - Checking how install only bind9 package from backports!

Comment: Edited the answer. That is the version I am using (Debian Jessie default)

Comment: Oh, ok man thanks! I was going insane to figure out where to put the response-policy block xD

Comment: How I can default the action of my rpz-foreign, my policy to reply just an A record 127.0.0.1 ? Because in the upper example you have the whitelist that goes out from the response-policy block but the rpz-foreign is not configured for do nothing. If you have better suggestions or alternatives than pointing to 127.0.0.1 it would be nice, but still cover the case in the answer if you can please :)

Comment: I use `TLD CNAME .` for instance I have `om CNAME .` because it is being used for cybersquatters for mistyping .com.  In your case, I think a `* CNAME A 127.0.0.1` will do. I do not have the time to test it for a few hours now. The upper example is actually my blacklist as I do not whitelist.

Comment: Ok fine but exactly wich part makes the filter being active? For example i tried this: `zone "rpz-foreign" policy DROP;` This way works however the request is put in timeout, i want instead a super fast reply so i was thinking of default all on 127.0.0.1 ;) or.. to a local webserver displaying some page or replying with a blank png/gif file.

Comment: The default policy does what you want, better not  add policy.  for instance in the zone file *.connectify A 127.0.0.1

Comment: So i fear i have some problems with my config, maybe given by the fact I'm also using a forwarder. I will post all my config soon in a new post in case. I'm using forward only; and Opendns servers as forwarders { 208.67.222.222; 208.67.220.220 }