# SSH and ddns: can connect remotely but not locally

Tags: ssh, remote, router, domain, dynamic-dns

I have set up a [no-ip](https://www.noip.com/) account to access my ssh server at home remotely with `myserver.ddns.net`, which works well.. from outside only.

#### From outside:

Remote ping:

```
$ ping myserver.ddns.net # success
```

Remote ssh:

```
$ ssh myserver.ddns.net # success
```

#### From local:

Local ping:

```
$ ping 192.168.2.8 # success
```

Local ssh:

```
$ ssh 192.168.2.8 # success
```

Remote ping:

```
$ ping myserver.ddns.net # success, resolving to 90.113.108.192
```

Remote ssh:

```
$ ssh myserver.ddns.net # loOong time waiting, then..
Connection closed by 90.113.108.192 port 22
```

Why could it be so?

Comment: You haven't set portforwarding on your router from local addresses, only from externals.

Comment: Firewall rules, routes....not enough data from your post.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Question edited to add more info. Is this enough?

Comment: @IporSircer the only NAT/PAT option seemed to be `internal port` and `external port` which I've both set to 22. I couldn't find any interesting configuration options with the keywords "forward port local".. From my router point of view, what is the difference between forwarding from local and forwarding from outside?

Comment: You've already experienced the difference: one works and the other doesn't. Most of the router firmwares doesn't have this feature, you have to use special (openwrt, ddwrt) images to achieve this.

Comment: Many routers don't allow LAN addresses to loop back to the WAN address. I ran into that problem and set up a DNS server on the intranet as a workaround. I'd be interested in an alternate solution.

Comment: @IporSircer wow. I cannot flash a custom image to my box, can I? I think it is property of my ISP :\

Comment: @Fox wow. Do you have any pointer about this workaround? How heavy was it? Does my ssh server could also be used as its own-dedicated dns server?

Comment: The SSH server could be used as a DNS server, yes. For your whole network even. I use BIND9. It's under 2 MB of files including configuration and the executables. `top` says it's using 0.0% CPU and ~60MB RAM. Arch has a [tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/BIND) that might be useful.

Comment: @Fox Cheers! As an alternate solution, maybe someone will help us [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346036) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer about accessing NAT from an internal network is, more correctly: you do not want to do that because of:

- restrictions of consumer-grade technology;
- performance reasons - NAT uses more CPU resources and memory -  albeit in a domestic scale it is not worrisome;
- routing more complex - either using and debbuging.

The alternatives are:

- if accessing only from that local server, creating an host file entry;
- creating a name server, and creating views if a public DNS name that belongs to you - not the case you present, but usually in an enterprise;
- creating a name server, and creating a custom internal name, like ssh.home;
- using BIND+RPZ, and redefining the external name to your internal IP address;
- if doing routing with a Linux box, with iptables+NAT, capturing the SSH sessions to your external IP, and NATing them to your internal IP address.

About my comments about capturing the IP address/creating the host file, see this answer how I deal at home with my DDNS address. [Better method for acting on IP address change from the ISP?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269567/better-method-for-acting-on-ip-address-change-from-the-isp/314280)

For BIND+RPZ see:

[Configure BIND as Forwarder only (no root hints), encrypted + RPZ blacklist / whitelist all together](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270716/configure-bind-as-forwarder-only-no-root-hints-encrypted-rpz-blacklist-wh)

[Large zone file for bind9 : ad-blocking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253841/large-zone-file-for-bind9-ad-blocking/253879)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from the comments and [this page](http://opensimulator.org/wiki/NAT_Loopback_Routers), I understand that it is a common security feature for routers not to accept such "**NAT loopbacks**": *i.e.* connecting from a local machine to another local machine *via* an external domain resolution.

As workarounds, I have been suggested to:

- use a custom image like openwrt or ddwrt in place of my native router softwares. (cheers to [Ipor Sircer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182562/))
- set up a local DNS server (cheers to [Fox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/175857))

Feel free to offer any other item I could append to this list :)

Comment: The problem is not the domain resolution, but routing/port forwarding or NAT only working from the outside.